# Calculate the square root of a number without a built-in function (such as Math.sqrt())

Tags: java

```
double n = 50, x = 1, last_x = 1;
do {
    last_x = x;
    System.out.println(last_x);
    x = (x + n / x) / 2;
} while (last_x != x);
System.out.println("Result: " + x);
```

Can anyone please explain to me why we assign x=(x+n/x)/2?

Comment: Because that is the formula for applying newton's method to finding square roots: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root. Alternatively the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)

Comment: Did you even try to research square root algorithms? This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: Sure.  If `x > 0` and `x` is an approximation to `sqrt(n)`, then `(x + n / x) / 2` will generally be a better approximation.